# Cross product of sets using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote the following recursive routine to compute cross product of two sets.

```
def combine(input1,input2,output):
    if len(input2)==0:
        return output
    else:
       for num in input1:
           output.append((num,input2[0]))
       combine(input1,input2[1:],output)

input1=[1 2 5]
input2=[2 3]
output=[(1,2), (1,3), (2,2),(2,3),(5,2),(5,3)]
```

Is it possible to make the recursion better, for example removing the loop in else and trying to do in same function. I'm looking at different ways of solving the problem.

Edit: Not looking for a solution with something in-built. Looking for how can I do recursion differently, and not use itertools.product.

Comment: Do you know about `itertools.product`?

Comment: I think your final `combine` call needs a `return` in front of it.

Comment: Would you please explain why you want a recursive solution? This is still unclear.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest recursive definition of the cartesian product I can think of looks like this. You can see that like yours, this has a loop -- actually, two loops embedded in a list comprehension. Unlike yours, this can handle two or more sequences:

```
def product(*seqs):
    if not seqs:
        return [[]]
    else:
        return [[x] + p for x in seqs[0] for p in product(*seqs[1:])]
```

Here's a walk-through to give you a sense of how it works. By definition, the cartesian product of an empty sequence (`product()`) is a sequence containing the empty sequence. In other words, `product()` == `[[]]` -- [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) for why.

Now let's say we call `product([1, 2, 3])` -- `seqs` is non-empty, so the return value is the result of the list comprehension. In this case, `product(*seqs[1:])` == `product(*[])` == `product()` == `[[]]`, so the list comprehension is equivalent to this:

```
[[x] + p for x in seqs[0] for p in [[]] ]
```

Which is equivalent to all of these:

```
[[x] + [] for x in seqs[0]]
[[x] for x in seqs[0]]
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

Adding another sequence, we have `product([4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3])`. Now the list comprehension looks like this:

```
[[x] + p for x in [4, 5, 6] for p in product(*seqs[1:])]
[[x] + p for x in [4, 5, 6] for p in [[1], [2], [3]]]
[[4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [6, 1], [6, 2], [6, 3]]
```

The pattern continues from there; for each additional sequence, each of the values in the sequence is prepended to each of the values in the cartesian product of the following sequences.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I used your implementation [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29654551/1774667) to do a compile time cross product in C++ for my amusement.

Answer (score 2):

Use itertools

```
import itertools

print list(itertools.product(input1, input2))
```

Semantically this is equivalent to:

```
for i_1 in input_1:
    for i_2 in input_2:
        for i_3 in input_3:
            ...
                for i_n in input_n:
                    #do something with i_1, i_2, i_3, ..., i_n
```

Where n is the number of arguments you pass to `product`.

Comment: This completely misses the point of the OP, which is how to improve the recursion.

Comment: @tcaswell: to be fair, the original version said "I'm looking at different ways of solving the problem" and didn't contain the last paragraph, so this made sense at the time.